# How do I fix 'Invalid character value for cast specification' on a date column in flat file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, etl, ssis

I have a CSV file with a {LF} delimiting each row and a date column with the date format as `"12/20/2010"` (including quotation marks)

My destination column is a SQL Server 2008 database table of type date (not datetime)

In my Flat File Connection Manager, I have configured the date column to be data type **`date [DT_DATE]`** with TextQualified set to true and the column delimiter as **`{LF}`** (it is the last column on each row). I have the text qualifier set to **`"`**

When I try to load this into an OLE Destination I get the following error

> [TRN_DORPS [760]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification.".
>   [TRN_DORPS [760]] Error: There was an error with input column ""CYCLE_DATE"" (874) on input "OLE DB Destination Input" (773). The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

If I attach a data viewer, the value in the pipeline is *`2010-12-20 00:00:00.0000000`* - is this time component what's causing the problem? I try to strip out the time component with `(DT_DATE)(DT_DBDATE)[CYCLE_DATE]` but to no avail as it stays the same in the pipeline

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was ultimately able to resolve the solution by setting the column type in the flat file connection to be of type "database date [DT_DBDATE]"

Apparently the differences between these date formats are as follow:

DT_DATE
A date structure that consists of year, month, day, **and hour**.

DT_DBDATE
A date structure that consists of year, month, and day.

DT_DBTIMESTAMP
A timestamp structure that consists of year, month, hour, minute, second, and fraction

By changing the column type to DT_DBDATE the issue was resolved - I attached a Data Viewer and the CYCLE_DATE value was now simply "12/20/2010" without a time component, which apparently resolved the issue.

Comment: +1 - Although this wasn't my exact issue, it was still very informative.

Answer (score 48):

In order to simulate the issue that you are facing, I created the following sample using `SSIS 2008 R2` with `SQL Server 2008 R2` backend. The example is based on what I gathered from your question. This example doesn't provide a solution but it might help you to identify where the problem could be in your case.

Created a simple CSV file with two columns namely order number and order date. As you had mentioned in your question, values of both the columns are qualified with double quotes (") and also the lines end with Line Feed (\n) with the date being the last column. The below screenshot was taken using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), which can display the special characters in a file. LF in the screenshot denotes Line Feed.

[image: Orders file]

Created a simple table named `dbo.Destination` in the SQL Server database to populate the CSV file data using SSIS package. Create script for the table is given below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Destination](
    [OrderNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OrderDate] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

On the SSIS package, I created two connection managers. **SQLServer** was created using the OLE DB Connection to connect to the SQL Server database. **FlatFile** is a flat file connection manager.

[image: Connections]

Flat file connection manager was configured to read the CSV file and the settings are shown below. The red arrows indicate the changes made.

Provided a name to the flat file connection manager. Browsed to the location of the CSV file and selected the file path. Entered the double quote (`"`) as the text qualifier. Changed the Header row delimiter from {CR}{LF} to `{LF}`. This header row delimiter change also reflects on the Columns section.

[image: Flat File General]

No changes were made in the Columns section.

[image: Flat File Columns]

Changed the column name from *Column0* to `OrderNumber`.

[image: Advanced column OrderNumber]

Changed the column name from *Column1* to `OrderDate` and also changed the data type to `date [DT_DATE]`

[image: Advanced column OrderDate]

Preview of the data within the flat file connection manager looks good.

[image: Data Preview]

On the `Control Flow` tab of the SSIS package, placed a `Data Flow Task`.

[image: Control Flow]

Within the Data Flow Task, placed a `Flat File Source` and an `OLE DB Destination`.

[image: Data Flow Task]

The `Flat File Source` was configured to read the CSV file data using the FlatFile connection manager. Below three screenshots show how the flat file source component was configured.

[image: Flat File Source Connection Manager]

[image: Flat File Source Columns]

[image: Flat File Source Error Output]

The `OLE DB Destination` component was configured to accept the data from Flat File Source and insert it into SQL Server database table named `dbo.Destination`. Below three screenshots show how the OLE DB Destination component was configured.

[image: OLE DB Destination Connection Manager]

[image: OLE DB Destination Mappings]

[image: OLE DB Destination Error Output]

Using the steps mentioned in the below 5 screenshots, I added a data viewer on the flow between the Flat File Source and OLE DB Destination.

[image: Right click]

[image: Data Flow Path Editor New]

[image: Configure Data Viewer]

[image: Data Flow Path Editor Added]

[image: Data Viewer visible]

Before running the package, I verified the initial data present in the table. It is currently empty because I created this using the script provided at the beginning of this post.

[image: Empty Table]

Executed the package and the package execution temporarily paused to display the data flowing from Flat File Source to OLE DB Destination in the data viewer. I clicked on the run button to proceed with the execution.

[image: Data Viewer Pause]

The package executed successfully.

[image: Successful execution]

Flat file source data was inserted successfully into the table `dbo.Destination`.

[image: Data in table]

Here is the layout of the table dbo.Destination. As you can see, the field **OrderDate** is of data type **date** and the package still continued to insert the data correctly.

[image: Destination layout]

This post even though is not a solution. Hopefully helps you to find out where the problem could be in your scenario.

Comment: I am amazed that you didn't create a registered account. Or why is your name grayed out? Wonderful answer. +1

Comment: Oh, and thanks for teaching me about *Data viewers*. You just saved me from hundreds of hours of work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a wrong value for a date, i.e I had a query that was running against `2022-09-31` which is incorrect as the month of September is not a 31 days month. Changing it to `2022-09-30` worked fine.